# Use drush to sync module configurations, not entire DB?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drush

I just learned of the awesome power of sites aliases and drush sql-sync. This is great. Is there a way to sync not the entire DB, but rather just the module configuration settings for one module?

The reason that I ask is because I have a default/master site and a number of multisites. These sites all use the modules of the default/master site, but some of them have custom configurations of those modules (so they do not share the same database).

When I add a new module and configure it to the master site, this means repeating that work for the multisites. It would be nice to do something like drush sql-sync @default.dev moduleName @multi1.dev moduleName

Then I would not have to repeat the work to add the module to each multisite, but I could then go into the multisites and tweak off of the copied-over settings.

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm a drush newb.

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently possible with drush aliases. I suggest you to take a look at these three topics related to your configuration:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71361/drush-sql-sync-not-working-on-multisite
- http://eporama.com/ramblings/drush-aliases
- https://drupal.org/node/1316378

I hope you will find a way to solve your problem :o)